# Showing a function is continuous on every point in $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $K > 0$ and let $f : \mathbb R  \rightarrow  \mathbb R $satisfy the condition $|f(x) - f(y)|  \leq  K|x - y| $for all $x, y  \in  \mathbb R$. Show that $f$ is continuous at every point $c \in \mathbb R$.

Here's my attempt:

> $|f(x) - f(y)|  \leq  K|x - y|  \rightarrow  |f(x) - f(y)|/K \leq  |x
> > - y|$
>
> In order for $f$ to have a limit at $c: |x - c| <  \delta   \rightarrow  |f(x) - f(c)| <  \epsilon$
>
> Let $\delta  =  \epsilon$/(2K)$
>
> $|f(x) - f(y)|/K  \leq  |f(x) - f(c)|/K + |f(y) - f(c)|/K <  \epsilon /(2K)
> > +  \epsilon /(2K) =  \epsilon /K$
>
> $|f(x) - f(y)| <  \epsilon$

Am I on the right path?

Comment: y can be c. Why you use y in order to show the continuity at c?

Comment: The definition of continuity should be $|x-c|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$. In this case, choose $\delta=\epsilon/K$

Comment: In order for $f$ to have a limit at $c$, you must show that, for any given $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|x - c| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(c)| < \varepsilon.$ Notice that, you must change your $y$ for $c$.

Comment: @User Yes that was a mistake, I've changed that now

Comment: @BAI I'm not sure what you are trying to say because if $\delta$ = $\epsilon$/K then the inequality below that would become |f(x) - f(y)|/K < 2$\epsilon$/K

Comment: @sjbhalli By changing $y$ for $c$ in your proof, you just need to consider $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{K}$.

Comment: @User I see what you are saying now

Comment: @sjbhalli $|f(x)-f(c)|\leq K|x-c|<K\epsilon/K=\epsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. Set $\delta= \frac {\epsilon}{K}$ then

Clearly $\delta>0$. Suppose that $x,y\in \mathbb R$ and $|x-y|<\delta$. Then by the given condition on  $f$ we have $|f(x)-f(y)|\le K|x-y|<K\delta=\epsilon$, so $f$ is in fact uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$>

Comment: That was super simple, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Let $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $\varepsilon>0$. We need to find a $\delta>0$ such that $$0<|x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon.$$ Choosing $\delta:=\varepsilon/K$ does the trick, since $$|f(x)-f(c)|\leq K|x-c|<K \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{K}=\varepsilon.$$ Hence $f$ is continuous at $x=c$. Since $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is arbitrary, $f$ is continuous in the real line.

**NOTE:** A function that satisfies the inequality in your hypothesis is called *Lipschitz continuous*.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ be a real number and let $\varepsilon >0$. By definition of continuity at $x=a$, we need to find $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$.

Almost done, just put $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{K}$, hence $$|f(x)-f(a)| \leq K |x-a| < K \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{K}=\varepsilon.$$
Since $a \in \mathbb R$ is arbitrary, the $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.